# How to scrape values of an array under a "ul" tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get values from "ul" element but there is no "li" items in it. Instead it has tag with array values. Like below.

```
<div class ="family">
<ul class ="age">
<ll-per-person count ="[4, 36, 60]" extracount="[]"></ll-per-person>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the count values. This is the code I have tried in python

```
r = requests.get(**url**)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'family'})
for ul in table.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'age'}):
    print(ul)
    for li in ul.findAll('ll-per-person'):
        print(li)
        for numbers in li.findAll(attrs = {"ll-per-person" : "count"}):
            print(numbers)
```

I'm getting output for "print(ul)" and "print(li)". But not "print(numbers)". Not getting any error too.
I need to get the values of count which is an array. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this because `count` is the attribute of `ll-per-person` and you can get attribute of element like this.

```
for li in ul.findAll('ll-per-person'):
    print(li["count"])
```

If it helps with your problem then don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved the problem. I'm not a web developer. So, do you know the name for that particular type of html syntax. If it is not a <li> inside a <ul>, then what it is called?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question! Can you ask again with some examples/details?

Comment: `<ul class ="age">
<ll-per-person count ="[4, 36, 60]" extracount="[]"></ll-per-person>
</ul>` 

What will the tag inside the "ul" tag be called. What type of declaration is that?

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand your question again. If it is important then please try asking another time!I am getting that if you are taking about other tags like `li` inside `ul`, you want to change `ll-per-person` to new tag?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have seen only `li` inside `ul` . Means list inside unordered list. But this `ll-per-person` is different which I haven't seen before. What is that? Name for this type of syntax ? I don't want to change anything in the code, I just want to know more about this syntax.

Comment: Oh! yeah! HTML is like this, you can use any name for tags. If you are using inbuit tag then it will work as expected but if you are using other name then also it is okay. It is not going to making any problem of you, like this using `ll-per-person` instead of `li`  is okay. Hope I am able to answer you question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the numbers from `<ll-per-person>` tag you can use `json` module for example:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class ="family">
<ul class ="age">
<ll-per-person count="[4, 36, 60]" extracount="[]"></ll-per-person>
</ul>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for item in soup.select("ll-per-person"):
    lst = json.loads(item["count"])
    print("Numbers are:")
    for number in lst:
        print(number)
```

Prints:

```
Numbers are:
4
36
60
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it is working. But I'm going with @Kshitiz solution as it is more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "u" tag has `<ll-per-person count="[4, 36, 60]" extracount="[]"></ll-per-person>` as its second child **(Use `soup.u.contents` to view the children)** we can access it and get the value of `count` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html_doc = """
<div class ="family">
<ul class ="age">
<ll-per-person count ="[4, 36, 60]" extracount="[]"></ll-per-person>
</ul>
</div>"""
soup = bs(html_doc,'html.parser')
tag_ll =  soup.ul.contents[1]

print(tag_ll['count'])
```